# Hitting hard memory limit when loading large image, possible to downsample while loading?

Tags: google-app-engine, imagemagick, out-of-memory, php-7, imagick

I need to generate small thumbnails from potentially gigantic images (10,000 x 10,000). I'm using ImageMagick and PHP running in Google App Engine. My GAE has a hard memory limit of 512 MB.

I've been trying to read the documentation for the imagemagick php extension, but the docs are pretty thin. I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543899/how-to-prevent-image-bombs-with-imagemagick) that has an answer from the maintainer and tried to adapt their code. I tried to set the resource area so that images which were larger than 2000x2000 pixels would get swapped out to disk instead of held in memory, but either I misunderstand the code or I'm doing something wrong. My GAE still crashes saying that I've filled the memory.

```
try {
    Imagick::setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA, 2000 * 2000);
    Imagick::setResourceLimit(Imagick::RESOURCETYPE_DISK, 1024*1024*1024*2);

    $im = new \Imagick($path);
    
    // ...

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    error_log("Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
}
```

`Exceeded hard memory limit of 512 MB with 514 MB...`

On Android devices, when loading a Bitmap from disk, there is an [option to downsample it as it is being loaded into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408737/416631). That allows me to load smaller versions of the image into memory and avoid the problem of gigantic files breaking everything.

Is there something similar in ImageMagick? I saw [ImageMagick::setSamplingFactors()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setsamplingfactors.php) but the documentation doesn't explain the parameters at all so I'm not sure how to use it.

How can I generate a tiny thumbnail from a giant image without hitting my hard memory limit on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 2):

If you are shrinking JPEG images, then imagemagick supports shrink-on-load. For example, here's a 10k x 10k pixel JPEG image being sized down to 200x200.

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e \
    convert wtc.jpg -resize 200x200 x.jpg
713340:2.98
```

That's 720MB of peak memory use and almost 3s of CPU time. Now try this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e \
    convert -define jpeg:size=400x400 wtc.jpg -resize 200x200 x.jpg
35952:0.32
```

Down to 35MB of memory and 300ms of CPU.

The `-define jpeg:size=400x400` hints to the JPEG loader that you want an image of at least 400x400 pixels, so (in this case) during load, it'll fetch at 1/8th size. You need the load hint size to be at least 2x larger than your final output size to avoid aliasing.

You can set this from imagick with [`setOption`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setoption.php).

Unfortunately, many loaders do not support shrink-on-load. PNG is especially bad:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e \
    convert wtc.png -resize 200x200 x.jpg
828376:5.62
```

830MB and 5.6s.

You could consider other resize programs. [`vipsthumbnail`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html) is fast and low-memory for almost all file formats, for example:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e \
    vipsthumbnail wtc.png --size 200x200 -o x.jpg
58780:2.29
```

60MB and 2.3s for the same PNG file. Quality is the same as imagemagick.

It has a [PHP binding](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips) too -- you can write eg.:

```
$image = Vips\Image::thumbnail('somefile.jpg', 200);
$image->writeToFile('tiny.jpg');
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the shrink-on-load with the imagick php extension instead of the command line tools? I was able to find `setSize()` which claims to load the image at a smaller size, but when I actually try it the full size image is still loaded.

Comment: I think you need setOption. I added a link.

Comment: I'm taking a look at your vips library. I'm running my site on Google App Engine. I'm pretty sure I can't install 3rd party extensions. Is there a pure php version of this that doesn't rely on the compiled extension? Alternatively, do you know of a way to use your ext on Google App Engine?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used app engine. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments says the standard app engine environment supports third-party binaries for php7 so it sounds like it should be possible. Alternatively, they support deployment of containers via dockerfiles.